# How to remove fields from the billing address editing page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

On the my-account/edit-address/billing/ page I need to remove some fields. I did it this way:

```js
add_filter('woocommerce_billing_fields', 'customize_billing_fields', 20, 1);
function customize_billing_fields($fields)
{

  unset($fields['billing_company']);

  return $fields;
}

add_filter('woocommerce_default_address_fields', 'customize_default_address_fields', 20, 1);
function customize_default_address_fields($fields)
{

  unset($fields['country']);

  unset($fields['address_2']);

  return $fields;
}
```

The fields have been deleted but the changes I make to the fields are not saved. I think this is happening because I removed the required fields and that's why it doesn't let me through because they are empty.
I added code to make the fields optional:

```js
add_filter('woocommerce_billing_fields', 'customize_billing_fields', 20, 1);
function customize_billing_fields($fields)
{

  unset($fields['billing_company']);

  $fields['billing_company']['required'] = false;

  return $fields;
}

add_filter('woocommerce_default_address_fields', 'customize_default_address_fields', 20, 1);
function customize_default_address_fields($fields)
{

  unset($fields['country']);

  $fields['country']['required'] = false;

  unset($fields['address_2']);

  $fields['address_2']['required'] = false;

  return $fields;
}
```

But for some reason after that they look like this[image]
The fields that I deleted appeared, but they are not required and I can save new information in the fields. How to fix it?